# conditional @import and @media - CSS

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries

How to write a condtional CSS import for both desktop and iPad..

E.g. Following is an import for screen/print condtional import

```
@import url('/css/screen.css') screen;
@import url('/css/print.css') print;
```

Could you please tell how to write similar statement for iPad Safari? I mean specifically the media part..

Comment: This is exactly the reason handheld/mobile devices should have used the [`handheld` media group](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-groups). Unfortunately the revolution in mobile seemed to take a stance of ["better than `handheld`"](http://www.html5rocks.com/mobile/mobifying.html)(see 'media="handheld"' 1/4 of the way through).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no media query that is specially satisfiable only by Mobile Safari.

Comment: But as per Apple's recommendation, they prefer using the media query and not the user agent (specially for browser sniffing)..As per http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html